# Como eliminar correctamente un registro en 2 Tablas que están relacionadas?

Tags: mysql

Estoy un poco confundido el día de hoy ya que estoy tratando de eliminar a un usuario que esta registrado en la tabla **user**, y luego esta la tabla **hijos** en la cual se registra su mismo `email` y otros datos. El inconveniente que tengo es que quiero eliminar el `id`,`nombre_hijo` y `email_padre` de dicha tabla, y luego que se elimine el registro de la tabla **user** que tenga ese mismo `email` pero al querer realizar el **DELET** en una sola consulta, no me deja eliminar nada por que me dice **Mysql** que las tablas están relacionadas. 
Ya investigue y según, cuando tienes 2 o mas tablas relacionadas, la forma de eliminar es mediante el `ON DELET CASCADE`, que según la documentación, elimina los registros hijos que estén relacionados, pero solo me elimino el registro de la tabla **hijos** y no el registro de la tabla **user** en donde esta el mismo `email`.

**- Tabla hijos:**

[image]

**- Tabla user:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**- Claves de la Tabla hijos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo eliminar correctamente los registros relacionados con `ON DELET CASCADE`, o es mejor hacerlo sin la relaciones y evitarme este problema, ya que si quito las `foreing_key` que relacionan el campo `email_padre`de la tabla hijos con el campo `email` de la tabla user, seria mas facil haciendolo con `INNER JOIN`, no?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Primero debes de borrar los datos de la tabla a la cual está la relación, es decir, si tienes la tabla Hijo, la cual hace referencia a la tabla Padre, primero deberás borrar los registros que ocupes de la tabla Padre, pues así eliminarás primero aquello que no tiene dependencia para después borrar registros de la tabla Hijo. En este caso ya no tendrías problemas de llave foránea.

Comment: para poder hacer una eliminación necesitas saber si la integridad referencial esta definidad como NUL, RESTRICT o CASCADE ya que si es restrict no te lo va a permitir

Comment: @ShadowPaz Esta como CASCADE, esta en la imagen que adjunte.

Comment: cierto es ya respondí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que tienes la integridad referencial como CASCADE, te va a permitir hacer cambios, solo una aclaración el campo que vas a eliminar va a quedar como NULL

El procedimiento deberá ser:

1. Borra en la tabla principal el registro en cuestión te pongo el ejemplo si yo tengo una tabla posts y una usuarios, ambas están unidas por el id del usuario entonces si yo elimino un usuario, en la tabla post el renglón que tenía asociado un post con un usuario se marcará la casilla del usuario_id como null eso puede quedar así
2. Repites con base en mi ejemplo en eliminar el usuario y cuando en la tabla de posts se muestre un registro con el usuario_id como NULL lo eliminas también

> En estos casos siempre debes eliminar primero en la tabla1 que tiene
>   la llave primaria y posteriormente en la tabla2 que usa la llave
>   primaria de la tabla1 como llave foránea.

//Actualización con ejemplo

Tengo las tablas usuarios y posts y asumiendo que tengo registros en ambas le digo que quiero borrar todo de la tabla posts pero indicandole un id de usuario en especifico **por que si no hago eso me va a borrar toda la información**

```
CREATE DATABASE demo;

use demo;

create table users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TABLE posts(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(12),
    id_user INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_posts_users FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO users (user) values("alfa");
INSERT INTO users (user) values("beto");

INSERT INTO posts (title, id_user) values("primer post", 1);
INSERT INTO posts (title, id_user) values("segundo post", 2);

//Esta query eliminará la información de la tabla posts que tenga coincidencia con el id que yo mismo le estoy pasando
DELETE posts.* from posts
JOIN users
ON users.id = posts.id_user
WHERE users.id = 2;
```

El código anterior, me elimina como ya pudiste ver pero en la tabla que tiene la llave foránea es decir en la de posts y mi resultado será que ahora el renglón eliminado será **NULL**

**OJO PRIMERO EXPERIMENTA CON MI EJEMPLO Y CHECA SI SOLUCIONA TU NECESIDAD ANTES DE PROCEDER CON TU BASE DE DATOS**

Comment: Mmm entiendo, entonces seria algo asi como este ejemplo? `delete libros,editoriales
  from libros
  join editoriales
  on libros.codigoeditorial=editoriales.codigo
  where editoriales.nombre='Emece';`

Comment: dame 3 minutos te hare un ejemplo en código y lo anexo a la respyuesta

Comment: LISTO ya te puse un ejemplo

Comment: Wow, gracias hermano, realmente funcionó, así quedo mi consulta SQL: `DELETE user.* from user
JOIN hijos
ON user.email = hijos.email_padre
WHERE user.email = "juancarlos@gmail.com";` ¡Muchas gracias!